# How do you deal with separate threads fetching data in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi I am currently building an app which has the following properties:

1. uses Core Data for storage
2. has a feed which displays one item at a time
3. if out of items, app will call fetch from server asynchronously

Dealing with async fetching has been proven to be rather tricky.

Currently, we are storing the items fetched from the server directly into Core Data.

Every time the app needs a new item, we are querying Core Data for an unseen item.

We are seeing some significant impacts with regards to the performance of the app due to this constant querying of Core Data.

We thought of using an Array in memory and keep an index to it but the asynchronous aspect of fetching once we are out of item proves to be too complex as we have to use locks and other concurrency measures to keep the array thread safe.

Do you guys have any suggestions for how can I reduce my total calls to Core Data?

Comment: Have you profiled your app and confirmed the fetches are slow?

Comment: What concurrency type are you using?

Comment: What are the symptoms of the performance issues? CoreData has its own caching system in its MOC.

Comment: I would use a GCD queue on the main thread (or another thread, but always on the same thread) to access the array. This gives you thread-safe access to the array without the overhead and headaches of using locks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the trips to the persistent store to a minimum so fetch a reasonable number of items that you expect to display. Core Data is very efficient in faulting managed objects so the memory footprint shouldn't be an issue.

When you are running out of items to display but still have some left in the array, try and fetch some more.

At this point, if you get no results, dispatch an async queue with its own managed object context, create the new managed objects, save and notify the main context so it can merge the changes.

Once that's done, you're back to fetching the new items.